# Can we debug a UI backwards, starting from its current state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, web, computer-science

In the context of web-development many times users provide screenshots of their "invalid state".

I use React and I was wondering if we could debug the opposite way: starting from the current state:

- User gives us screenshot of invalid UI state.
- Via devtools we change props of components to match & find that specific permutation (let's imagine all components are stateless).
- Feed the permutation to "a program" that shows us the things in our code that caused the props to change that way.

From a technical point of view I wonder whether this is even possible: can we go backwards in time from a specific state of a program?

This should be possible since the state is derived from a specific execution path of our code; so the opposite should also be possible? The reason I am interested is for debugging purposes but I also feel it would be an interesting exploratory excercise.

Are there any resources or tools that I can look into to find if this is possible?

**EDIT**: to make this a bit more clear I'm looking for a way to give the system as input a "state", and return a possible list of "path traces" in time that my code could execute to arrive at such state:

```
showHowWeCanArriveTo({
  name: 'Bob',
  showPopup: true,
  colors: ['blue', 'green']
});

// Returns:
[
  [setName('Bob'), setShowPopup(true), addColor('blue'), addColor('green')]
]
```

Comment: This is probably impractical. Theoretically you may be able to evaluate a combination of actions which lead to a particular outcome, but also theoretically that set of possible combination would be infinite. You could always throw one more button click in which doesn't change the outcome, but forms part of the chain of events. Even if you solved that issue, the more dynamic your program the less decidable it becomes, e.g. any `foo[prompt()] = prompt()` becomes entirely undecidable in practice…

Comment: Yes that's what I thought. I'm curious if there paradigms or languages that enable one to program with less dynamism of permutations - a sort of "only these actions can be taken" language.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61203537/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/124084/755.   Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Logrocket](https://logrocket.com/) before in react for that exact same purpose. If you're using redux, they provide a middleware that logs the user state and its history and is accessible from their web.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for [time travel debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_travel_debugging), [reverse debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger#Reverse_debugging), or [replay debugging](http://www.replaydebugging.com/2008/08/vmware-workstation-65-reverse-and.html).  Basically, they work by recording what the program is doing as it executes and keeping enough logs that you can then go backwards.

Alternatively, it is possible in principle to use techniques from program analysis (program slicing, reverse program execution, etc.) to try to execute the program in reverse and find all execution paths that might lead to that state.  However, there might be many such paths (the further back you go, the more there might be), and implementing such a thing from scratch is technically non-trivial.